# Is it possible to call a C++ object instance's destructor before its constructor? If so, how?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to call a C++ object instance's destructor before its constructor?

Not that I actually want to do this, but I am wondering if it were to occur if it is definitely an indication of a compiler bug, or if there is a way for some errant C++ code to cause this obviously incorrect behavior (even if it's a contrived example).

I got to wondering about this when I noticed a pattern of measuring time in a time-logging constructor/destructor pair, and the code contained the implicit assumption: destructor time >= constructor time.

Presumably this assumption is always correct, given the same clock... And if violated, I would suspect a clock "problem" before suspecting a compiler bug.

So... is it possible? And if so, how?

Comment: You can always do: `reinterpret_cast<T*>(some_buffer)->~T()`, where that buffer was never constructed as a `T`. Does that count?

Comment: It is possible to directly call a destructor, yes, but it results in undefined behavior if the target object is not constructed. But the compiler shouldn't be doing this as a matter of course. Timer/clock issues are indeed more likely. Show some code.

Comment: It would be great if you could post some code to demonstrate whatever you're seeing. It's hard to figure out what might be going on from a description. (But the answer is no, that should never happen unless you write some weird code to explicitly call the destructor of a nonexistent object.)

Comment: Have you considered that the lifetime of your object may be less than the resolution of your clock?

Comment: Barry, yes it counts. cdhowie and Mike Seymour, I have no misbehavior I'm actually seeing, the question simply occurred to me as I was examining code that assumed a time delta between ctor and dtor was always positive. sjdowling, yes, the code expects the delta might be 0. But not negative or undefined...

Comment: @sjdowling he does - ">=" for time not ">"

Comment: @Slava more precisely, the code does subtraction and then expects the result >= 0

Comment: Not all clocks are monotonic, e.g., [`std::chrono::system_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock). It's possible for the destructor to run "before" the constructor if the clock's value changes. Causality is confusing in the presence of time travel ;)

Comment: FWIW: I've actually encountered the problem.  Due to a compiler bug.  But that was a long, long time ago.  (It's more frequent for the compiler to not call a destructor when it should.)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, sure you can do that. It's only UB.
The simplest way is calling a dtor on a value whose lifetime you manage explicitly anyway:

```
union{std::vector<int> v;}; // This disables automatic dtor/ctor calls. Needs C++11
v.~vector<int>();
```

Calling a dtor before the ctor on an object is safe only if the ctor and/or the dtor is trivial (aka do-nothing).
Also known as, the object is always initialized.

I don't actually know of any reason to call the dtor but never/before the ctor.
Though it is possible to think of situations where you want to avoid calling either.

Anyway, you might want to be sure to use a monotonic clock-source, as e.g. local time (or the system clock) can and is adjusted backwards occassionally (DST, clock skew).

Comment: I do not think OP really asking how to do that, but can he expect that nobody else would do it

Comment: @0x499602D2 by putting it in a union the ctor won't be called is my best guess. If you just create a variable without the union the ctor will be called.

Comment: @ted Can't it also be in an anonymous `struct`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 No, a `struct` is just a `class` by a different name (and with different default-access).

Comment: @0x499602D2 as deduplicator wrote, a struct is a class, all its members have their default constructors called.

Comment: @Deduplicator In pre-C++11, you can't put a type with a non-trivial constructor in a union.  You can, however, call the destructor on any memory, using casts.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I often pitty those stuck on pre-C++11 compilers. Especially if it's me. This question is tagged C++11 though... still, thanks for that, adding it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes technically it is possible to write such code. But I believe you are really asking "would somebody do it"? I cannot imagine a situation when such situation would be necessary. So I think you can expect that this should not happen in properly written program, but keep in mind that it is possible to meet such situation (you may decide to produce diagnostics in such case).